# Как сделать видео чат с отправлением запросов другу с WebRtc?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, webrtc

Как сделать видео чат в котором, например я пишу в инпуте имя друга и ему отправляется запрос на чат, если он его принимает - начинать с помощью WEBRTC. Как можно так сделать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Много разных примеров как это сделать:**

1. [WebRTC code samples](https://github.com/webrtc/samples)
2. [WebRTC demos and samples](https://github.com/cwilso/webrtc/tree/master/samples/web/content)

Выбирайте что вам нужно.